# C# TCP Client for WM6

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, tcpclient

Im trying to make a TCP client application for a PDA with Windows Mobile 6 Professional.
I tried to make it first on my laptop and it worked. The code for the "smart device" is exaclty the same but it doesn't work.

Here it is the code:

```
// IP and Port
string IP = "192.168.1.68";
int port = 1000;

// TCP connection
TcpClient connection;
StreamReader TCPreader;
StreamWriter TCPwriter;

//(...)

    try
    {
        connection = new TcpClient(IP, port);
        NetworkStream stream = connection.GetStream();
        TCPreader = new StreamReader(stream);
        TCPwriter = new StreamWriter(stream);

        // wait for welcome message
        status_label.Text = TCPreader.ReadLine();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
    }
```

An exception is thrown on "readLine()" method call. I can't get the message, otherwise I get something like this "this exception message is not installed, you have to install NETCFv35.messages.en.cab". I already installed that .cab but I get the same message.

What is going wrong? Why this code works on my laptop (WinForms app/NET3.5) and doesn't on PDA (Smart Device/NETCF3.5)? Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you connecting to the network via the PDA? Is 192.168.1.68 reachable by the PDA? You can use http://wmnettools.codeplex.com/ to debug network issues.

Comment: This is what I have: a laptop, Arduino with a WiShield (if you dont know what is it, its hardware with a TCP stack and a TCP server running in it) and a PDA (HTC Touch with WM6). With my laptop I have no problems. I can "ping" 192.168.1.68 and send/receive messages from it. With the PDA it seems to connect but I can't receive/send data. The firewall is disabled for testing purposes. I will try the application you refered.

Comment: Well after giving "Net Tools" a try, here it is what I get: "Request timed out" "Request timed out" "Request timed out" "ERROR, a native exception has ocurred in NetToolsV2.exe". Frustrating... Why PDA can't reach 192.168.1.68? Even with firewall disabled?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem. While my PDA is connected through USB to my laptop, WiFi is disabled. *Arghhh* I just disconnect PDA from my laptop and now I cant send/receive messagens from 192.168.1.68.

Thanks all for your hints!

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall, and that your server is running.

I'm not sure why you can't see the error messages; try casting it to `SocketException` and extracting the `ErrorCode`.

Comment: The firewall is disabled and I still get this error. Can't connect to TCP Server.